# Derivative function python

Tags: python

I need to write code for the derivation of the function without using NumPy or SymPy. Users should input function as polynomes (example: 2*x^3+5) and a number. The code should write n-th derivation of function (function 3*x^3 and number 2 (second derivation): 18*x^1). I have some of the code but I have problems with it: if a function is entered as 2*x^3+5*x it prints derivation only of 2*x^3 (or derives but in next line -like two separate functions) and it doesn't show the n-th derivation (but some number close to n). Some ideas for improving? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzJJU.png)

Code:

```
a=input("Polinom:")

b=int(input("Number:"))  

z=a.split("+")



i,j=0

while i<b:

    for j in range(len(z)):
        coeff=int(z[j][0])
        exp=int(z[j][-1])
        e=("{}x^{}".format(coeff*exp,exp-1))

        print(e)
        z.append(e)


    coeff=coeff*exp
    exp=exp-1
    i+=1
```

Comment: You need to put your real code in the question, not an image of it.

Comment: This is just derivatives for polynomials, correct?

Comment: minor correction: `i,j=0` => `i,j = 0,0`

Comment: You should always give exponent on input: `x^1`, not `x`. There needs to be some exit from the `for` loop when `z[j][-1]` is 0. Also use `z[j].split("^")` instead of `z[j][-1]` (which won't work for exponents >= 10).

Comment: Any specification of format? For example, are you allowing scientific notation (e.g. `1.2e+3*x^4e+1`)? What about subtraction? You might consider using a recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this answer is based on your existing code, and simply shows how you could expand on that to improve what you have so far. 
It is not how I would usually go about differentation in python. 
I'll provide some explanations as comments in the code. 
A few assumptions: only polynomials are allowed. Scientific notation is not allowed. Your variable is denoted by `x` and the multiplication symbol is ommited.

```
import re

p = '2x^6-4x^5+3x^3' #example of polynomial
b = 3 #no of derivations
i=0
while i<=b:
    z = re.split('(\+|-)',p) #in your code you only check for +. - can also be present
    z = list(filter(None, z)) #output of the last couple lines of code: ['2x^6', '-', '4x^5', '+', '3x^3']
    deriv = '' #this is where we save the derivative expression
    for j in range(len(z)):
        if 'x' in z[j]: #only do something when we encounter a monome
            sign = ''
            if j!=len(z) - 1 and 'x' in z[j+2]: #we add the sign only if we are not at the end of  the list and if the next monome will not vanish during differentiation
                sign = z[j+1]
            coeff=int(z[j].split('x')[0]) #get coefficient
            exp = z[j].split('^') #split monome to get exponent
            if len(exp)>1:
                e = int(exp[1])
                if e - 1 > 1:
                    deriv+=("{}x^{}{}".format(coeff*e,e-1,sign)) if sign != '' else ("{}x^{}".format(coeff*e,e-1))
                else: #if x is of power 2, it will be shown as x and x^1
                    deriv+=("{}x{}".format(coeff*e, sign)) if sign != '' else ("{}x".format(coeff*e))
            else: #if x is of the power of 1, x will not be shown in the expression
                deriv+=("{}{}".format(coeff,sign)) if sign != '' else ("{}".format(coeff))

    print(deriv) #print the current derivative
    p = deriv    #current derivative becomes the next polynomial to differentiate 
    i+=1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great help, thanks! I will try to adapt it to the input I need to have: eg. 2*x^3 instead of 2x^3.